# how to iterate over extracted value with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I have no experience with XQuery. But I need to Know if it can do this before committing to it.

Can I iterate over a value that is extracted from an XML element using XQuery? The value will be a CSV string:

```
<element>1,2,3,a,b,c</element>
```

I would like to replicate this Python code with XQuery:

```
for x in xml_value.split(','):
    # do whatever
    print x

1
2
3
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments that Martin Honnen made:

```
for $x in tokenize(doc('xmldoc.xml')/csv, ',')
  return $x
```

Comment: The `for .. return` is not needed, the expression `tokenize(doc('xmldoc.xml')/csv, ',')` suffices and returns exactly the same result, namely a sequence of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string-join(tokenize(element, ','), '&#10;')` to produce the output you have shown.

Comment: thanks. will it work like: `for $x in string-join(tokenize(element, ','), '&#10;')`

Comment: No, the expression I posted evaluates to a single string containing the lines you have shown (as your desired output). If you want a sequence of strings then simply use `tokenize(element, ',')`.